# Injecting Moment Timezone

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, gulp, bower, momentjs

Hello I'm injecting the normal Moment with:

```
myApp.constant('moment', moment);
```

The dependency is coming from angular-moment in my gulpfile

```
resourcesFolder + 'assets/bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js',
resourcesFolder + 'assets/bower_components/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.js',
resourcesFolder + 'assets/bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.min.js'
```

How do I inject the timezone module?

Comment: You don't inject anything in the code above. You're defining `moment` service. As you can see [here](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone), the package extends the same `moment` global to provide functionality. You don't need to do extra actions in Angular to support it.

Comment: Thanks, silly me haha